# Custom exception showing a variable message, different behaviour in different compilers

Tags: c++, windows, exception, winsock2

I'm doing some socket programming lately and starting to code in C++. As the program I'm trying to write will have several components that have to communicate via sockets I decided to wrap up socket communication in a class.

Since there are several errors that can happen I decided to create a class for socket exceptions, I defined it like this:

```
class SocketException: public std::exception {
public:
  SocketException(const std::string &message);
  ~SocketException() throw();
  virtual const char * what() const throw();
private:
  std::string msg;
};
```

The implementation is as follows:

```
SocketException::SocketException(const std::string &message) : msg(message) {}
SocketException::~SocketException() throw() {}

const char * SocketException::what() const throw() {
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << msg + " Error number: ";
  stream << WSAGetLastError();
  return stream.str().c_str();
}
```

The implementation of the `what()` method is incomplete as of now, because I'd like to show the text meaning of the error code via `FormatMessage()` but I haven't written that yet.

I was trying this code in Visual Studio but instead of working as I expected the `what()` method returns garbage. After spending quite some time trying to figure out the problem and trying different things I ended up trying a different compiler.

Using MinGW (GCC) the code compiles and runs as expected, messages are shown as I thought they'd be (if anyone is interested I'm just trying to perform a `connect()` when not connected to the Internet).

I'm just learning C++, I'd like to know where the problem is or what would be the appropriate way of doing it.

EDIT: Thanks for the comment and answer, at first I thought that'd be the case so I used `new` to allocate the stream (even knowing it'd be a leak, just to try as I understand `new` uses the heap) and the result was the same, this is what I had:

```
const char * SocketException::what() const throw() {
  std::stringstream *stream = new std::stringstream();
  *stream << msg + " Error: ";
  *stream << WSAGetLastError();
  return (*stream).str().c_str();
}
```

Comment: You are invoking UB, the *stream* object will be destructed when the method returns so the char* returned by c_str() is a dangling pointer.  You'll need a char[] in your class to keep the pointer valid.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I thought that would be it but allocating the stream in the heap produced the same result. Could it be that the `str()` call creates a temporary object that's destroyed at some point?

Comment: Concerning the edit, yes, `stringstream::str()` returns a copy of the underlying string, which is a temporary in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a variable that is local to your `what` function, thus leaving the caller with a dangling pointer:

```
const char * SocketException::what() const throw() {
  std::stringstream stream;  // this stringstream will die on exiting this scope
  stream << msg + " Error number: ";
  stream << WSAGetLastError();
  return stream.str().c_str();
}
```

That is **undefined behaviour**. It means anything could happen.

An example of a method safely returning `const char*` would be this (obviously it doesn't have the intended functionality of the original, it is just for illustration purposes):

```
const char * SocketException::what() const throw()
{
  return msg.c_str(); // msg lives as long as this SocketException instance 
}
```

This has defined behaviour provided the pointer is not dereferenced after the `SocketException` object dies.

Comment: At first I thought of that too, so I tried using `new` to allocate the stream (even knowing it'd end up in a leak) and the result was the same. I understand new would allocate memory in the heap? I'll edit the question to show that. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: @A.Row you don't want to return a pointer to a dynamically allocated object. What you can do is return a pointer to a data member.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll be creating the custom message directly in the constructor of the class and just returning the message as you show.

Comment: @A.Row glad it helped. BTW I recommend en.cppreference.com as a reference. For example, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) you can see why your version with `new` didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, I'll keep it in the bookmarks from now on.

Answer (score 0):

How about
`throw std::runtime_error("My very own message");`